# Are there some decisions that the Federal Reserve can make only with the President's or the government's approval?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve

Are there some decisions that the Federal Reserve can make only with the President's or the government's approval? I am wondering if that's the case, because the Federal Reserve can decide to hold reserve currency of other countries. Let's say that the Federal Reserve wants to hold a significant amount of Russian or Chinese currency, let's say 100 billion. Does it need the approval of the government or can the Federal Reserve make its own decisions since it's an independent organization?

Comment: What do you mean by hold an amount of a currency? And for what purposes do you think it would do that?

Comment: @JoeW what do you **think** it means to hold currency?!

Comment: If the purpose of this question is to ask what are the regulations requi.red to freeze assets belonging to foreign countries it should be completely reformulated.

Comment: What makes you think the purpose of the question is to ask whether the Fed can freeze assets belong to foreign countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Federal Reserve Board is appointed by the President (with Senate approval), even though some of activities of Federal Reserve member banks are independent of the government. This is the primary and sanctioned means by which government approval is secured.

The Federal Reserve Banks are also the mandatory banking institutions with which federal government agencies can set up accounts. The Fed can't set up the accounts unilaterally, however, it must be requested by an agency, generally with the sponsorship and approval of the Treasury Department.

There are a number of key parameters of the Federal Reserve system that are established by statute with an Act of Congress. But, none of the kinds of decisions you are contemplating would ordinarily be decisions requiring approval of the President or the Treasury Department.